# improve load time of very long scrolling page of images

Tags: javascript, css, image, scroll, load

Ive got 5 very long images (each 7 scrolled pages long) and Im wondering how to get the best load time?

Would the best way be to cut each image up into 7 parts and then fade them in with javascript as they come into focus? Do you think I could get away with just fading the 5 very long images in?

Trying to get it so this is responsive as well.

Cheers

KE

Comment: isn't the best way loading scroll pages ajax? when the user is idle, focus on loading on screen items, when scrolling, preload further items

Answer (score 0):

Image tiling/slicing seems like a reasonable way to go, if for slightly more effort and and storing/delivering assets in a format that doesn't lend it'self to their being used elsewhere - if that's even a consideration here.

If you have control of the images could you deliver them in a format/setting that provides for [progressive rendering (interlacing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlacing_(bitmaps))?

See http://nuwen.net/png.html for a very good PNG focussed introduction to the topic.

Of course, if you're loading multiple images, you might get some improvement over starting loads when the view is approaching them, when the image above them completes or some combination of the two.